# How can I use .format with a list?

Tags: python, list, string.format

I'm still a beginner at Python, and was doing some simple code just to exercise. I defined a list with some names, so I could print it afterwards, but I can't really do it the way I want.

I did it kind of like this:

```
names = ['John', 'Karl', 'Anne', 'Beth']
print("Those kids' names are {}.".format(names))
```

It returns "Those kids' names are ['John', 'Karl', 'Anne', 'Beth']."

I wanted it to be displayed without the brackets ([]) and the quotes (''), like this:
"Those kids' names are John, Karl, Anne, Beth."

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.join` to join an iterable of strings with a given separator.

```
names = ['John', 'Karl', 'Anne', 'Beth']
print(f"Those kids' names are {', '.join(names)}.")
```